# Is there a way for Unix sort to ignore delimiter based on escape characters?

Tags: sorting, unix

I want to use Unix sort but sometimes I want the field delimiter if enclosed by a pair of enclosing delimiter to not be treated as the field delimiter. For example, lets look at the base case and then then later look at the specific case:

> Base Case:

```
"xyz"|27
"abc"|15 
"xyz"|25
```

When I perform the following command:

> sort -t'|' -k1,1 -k2,2n test1.txt

I get what I want:

```
"abc"|15
"xyz"|25
"xyz"|27
```

> Now let's look at the second case with an escape character pair <> provided:

```
"x<|>yz"|27
"abc"|15
"xyz"|25
```

If I run the same command, I get something that I don't want:

```
"abc"|15
"x<|>yz"|27
"xyz"|25
```

Is there anyway to tell unix sort that if <> or {} or () or even a weird pair like <) is provided, then ignore the actual field delimiter inside the enclosing delimiter pair? The actual field delimiter will always be a pipe.

The desired result that I am aiming for is:

```
"abc"|15
"xyz"|25
"x<|>yz"|27
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

short: `sort` doesn't do that.

long: you can mostly work around this by pre/post-filtering of the data to make the fields align in columns.  If I had to use just the command-line `sort`, I'd preprocess the file using `sed` so that the delimiter is a `tab` character (which in POSIX is before any printable character).  After sorting, replacing the `tab` with the vertical bar would be another `sed`-command.

For "mostly", the main pitfall is that in some locales, the various punctuation characters are essentially ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so but instead you could:

1. duplicate the key and clean the duplicate off the `<|>`
2. move the original key to the end
3. sort on the cleaned key
4. remove the cleaned key and move the original key back to its place

Using awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="([^|]+|(\"[^\"]+\"))";OFS="|"}{i=$1;gsub(/<.*>/,"",i);print i,$2,$1}' file | sort -t\| -k1 -k2 | awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="([^|]+|(\"[^\"]+\"))";OFS="|"}{print $NF,$2}'
"abc"|15
"xyz"|25
"x<|>yz"|27
```

Explained (1. and 2.):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="([^|]+|(\"[^\"]+\"))";OFS="|"}{i=$1;gsub(/<.*>/,"",i);print i,$2,$1}' file
```

outputs:

```
"xyz"|27|"x<|>yz"
"abc"|15|"abc"
"xyz"|25|"xyz"
```

Code explained:

```
BEGIN { 
    FPAT="([^|]+|(\"[^\"]+\"))"  # define fields to allow field separators in quotes
    OFS="|"                      # output field separator to |
}
{
    i=$1                         # copy first field to var i
    gsub(/<.*>/,"",i)            # remove "escaped" part
    print i,$2,$1                # output 
}
```

piping to `sort -t\| -k1 -k2` outputs (3.):

```
"abc"|15|"abc"
"xyz"|25|"xyz"
"xyz"|27|"x<|>yz"
```

Code explained:

```
...                               # see previous explanation
{
    print $NF,$2                  # print last first then second (original order)
}
```

and the result of (4.) is right up there.